# Custom directive not loading template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('fruitStore', []);

app.directive('productTitle', function(){
   return {
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
  };
});
```

index.html

```
<product-title></product-title>
```

product-title.html

```
{{ product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">{{ product.price | currency}}</em>
```

But the directive is not loading the template. What am I missing?

Comment: do you see any 404 errors in the network console? can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Are you sure the relative url 'product-title.html' resolves correctly from the page that would load it?

Comment: It seems to be an issue in chrome. I am running on a mac and when I when I ran chrome like this: open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files it works. Chrome was messing with the AJAX.

Comment: Then you must be having the cors issue

Comment: No solutions???? I am having the same issue.